# is it possible to delete data from database where the latest created_at?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I have the following table in db:

[image]

This is my delete code at controller:

```
public function destroy(Request $request){ DB::table( slip_gaji_has_tunjangan )->
          where( tenaga_kerja_idtenaga_kerja, $request->idkar)->
          where(at here i want created-at latest)->delete();
    }
```

Is possible to delete latest record with same id?

Comment: Add code here, not image of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `created_at` column , you can use `latest()`
So it would be like

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
    { 
        DB::table( slip_gaji_has_tunjangan )->
          where(tenaga_kerja_idtenaga_kerja, $request->idkar)->
          ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->limit(1)->delete();
    }
```

Comment: i got this error Call to undefined method stdClass::delete()

Answer (score 5):

```
Model::where('column_name', 'value')->latest()->first()->delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the code as follows

```
   DB::table('slip_gaji_has_tunjangan')
      ->where('tenaga_kerja_idtenaga_kerja',$request->idkar)
      ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first()->delete();
```

OR

```
  DB::table('slip_gaji_has_tunjangan')
      ->where('tenaga_kerja_idtenaga_kerja',$request->idkar)
      ->latest()->first()->delete();
```

OR

```
 DB::table('slip_gaji_has_tunjangan')
  ->where('tenaga_kerja_idtenaga_kerja',$request->idkar)
  ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->limit(1)->delete();
```

Comment: it is work thanks.. but i change first() with limit(1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select only one. That is to say the last one created and then delete it.

```
$query->where('created_at')->latest()->first()->delete()
```